# How do I print the last level of a category?

Tags: templating

Some categories have 2 levels, some only have 1 level.

How can I print the "last" level of an entry if for some it is level(2) and others it is level(1)?

Answer (score 1):

I've not actually done this, but I'm guessing:

`{% set category = entry.categoriesFieldHandle.last() %}`

(...then `.level` on that to get the level if that's what you want).  `.last()` is the opposite of `first()`.

(Make sure you check `category|length` as it might be that no categories are assigned...)